# pugh's mathematical analysis chapter 5 question 30

Tags: real-analysis

Consider the equation $xe^y+ye^x=0$

c) what is its derivative at $x=0$

d) what is its second derivative at x=0?

e) what does this tell you about the graph of the solution?

The question seems awfully straight forward, I am not sure if I am missing something, or I am not understanding the question correctly.

Here is what Ive tried, so I set $y=-xe^{y-x}$ and then $\frac{dy}{dx}=-e^{y-x}+(x\cdot (y^\prime(x)-x))$ then let $x=0$ we have $\frac{dy}{dx}=-1$

Comment: No.  You're supposed to use implicit differentiation and the product rule to find the derivative.

Comment: @RobertShore Thank you for the comment can you let me know if I am doing this correctly? So I set $y=-xe^{y-x}$ and then $\frac{dy}{dx}=-e^{y-x}+(x\cdot (y^\prime(x)-x))$ then setting $x=0$ we have $\frac{dy}{dx}=-e^{y(0)}=-1$

Comment: Remember that $f’(a)$ is rarely the derivative of $f(a)$.

Comment: Remember the derivative is about the rate of change at a point.  We may be looking at a specific point of $x$ at that exact point we get a specific value but the derivative refers to when when the equation is "in motion"  We *lose* that when we treat the equation as an evaluated value it a static point.

Comment: Please edit your question to incorporate your try.

Comment: Your try isn't quite correct, but the error vanishes because you're evaluating at $x=0$.  Specifically, the second term you get when applying the quotient rule is $x \cdot \frac{d}{dx} (e^{y-x})$.  That derivative doesn't evaluate to $y'(x)-x$, but because you're multiplying that term by $0$ the error doesn't effect your evaluation of the derivative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$xe^y+ye^x=0$.  Using the product rule and the chain rule to take the implicit derivative with respect to $x$, we have:

$$xe^y\dfrac{dy}{dx}+e^y+ye^x+e^x \dfrac{dy}{dx}=0 \\
\left (xe^y+e^x \right)\dfrac{dy}{dx}=-(e^y+ye^x) \\
\dfrac{dy}{dx}=-\dfrac{e^y+ye^x}{xe^y+e^x}.$$

As you've noted, evaluating at $x=0$ we have also $y=0$, so at $(0, 0)$ we have $\frac{dy}{dx}=-1.$

Can you see how to do the second derivative using the quotient rule?

Comment: Yes thank you! I do see how to do the second derivative using quotient rule.